# Declaration and filling of a two dimensional array in a struct in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, declaration

i'd like to create in a struct a two dimensional array, then fill it with some values, like that :

```
typedef struct {
Ez_image *image1;
Ez_window win1;
int coordJeu[16][2] = {{4,1},{3,2},{5,2},{2,3},{4,3},{6,3},{1,4},{3,4},{5,4},{7,4},{2,5},{4,5},{6,5},{3,6},{5,6},{4,7}};
} App_data;
```

This give me :

```
error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
 int coordJeu[16][2] = {{4,1},{3,2},{5,2},{2,3},{4,3},{6,3},{1,4},{3,4},{5,4},{7,4},{2,5},{4,5},{6,5},{3,6},{5,6},{4,7}};;
                     ^
```

I'd like to understand how to do that, and, if its not possible, how to fill the 2-dim array right after declaration, in something like that (assuming the following wont work, its just for the idea):

```
App_data gameDb;
gameDb.coordJeu[][] = {{4,1},{3,2},{5,2},{2,3},{4,3},{6,3},{1,4},{3,4},{5,4},{7,4},{2,5},{4,5},{6,5},{3,6},{5,6},{4,7}};
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
App_data gameDb = {
    .coordJeu = {{4,1},{3,2},{5,2},{2,3},{4,3},{6,3},{1,4},{3,4},{5,4},{7,4},{2,5},{4,5},{6,5},{3,6},{5,6} {4,7}};
};
```

A [designated initializer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) is used here.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks for the quick answer ! :D

Comment: @Bacquelmore Always glad to help :-)